# Can you create a link to open a User Control in a VB.Net form to use at Design time?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, windows-forms-designer

I've got a VB.Net form application that dynamically loads user controls based on which navigation link the user clicks on.  I'd like to make it easier to use at Design time by putting a link of some sort to open the User Control at design time.  The link would go onto the form in the space where the User Control will be going.  This just saves a little time from having to browse through the files to open the correct file.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather, this is not possible.  :(

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly then I think your best bet is a custom properties http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/UserControlDesigner.aspx In VS2008 you can then add them to the context menu.